# Trying to understand basic properties of the $p$-adic logarithms

Tags: number-theory, power-series, p-adic-number-theory

I know that the $p$-adic integral defined by 
$$
\log_p(1 + x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^n}{n}
$$
is well defined for $x \in \mathbb{C}_p$, the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, with $|x|_p < 1$.

I am wondering how does one see that 
$\log_p(1 + x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ given $x \in p \mathbb{Z}_p$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easier than it looks:
Using additive valuation, for which $v_pp=1$, so that $\vert z\vert_p=p^{-v_pz}$, we have $v_p(x^n)\ge n$, while $v_p(n)\le\log_p(n)$. Thus  $v_p(x^n/n)\ge1$, so the sum is in $p\Bbb Z_p$.

Answer (score 3):

You first need the following fact on series in the $p$-adics:

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if $|a_n|_p \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

The sufficient part is of course incorrect if we take the normal norm on $\mathbb R$, but this is true for non-archimedean norms, like the $p$-adic norm.

Let $a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^n$. Then $|a_n|_p = |n|_p^{-1}|x|_p^n \leq n |x|_p^n$, where the equality is attained only when $n = p^l$ for some $l \in \mathbb Z_{\geq0}$. So $|a_n|_p$ has limit $0$ whenever $|x|_p < 1$.

Comment: Thanks for this. I made the (likely unwarranted) assumption that OP understood why the series was convergent.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!